# Is it possible to use mouseleave() with an offset?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a padding/offset(say 5-10px) to how far out of element the cursor needs to be to trigger the jQuery mouseleave function.

I searched SO but didn't come across an answer.

Is this possible?

Comment: Unclear.. can you demonstrate or show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

If your current structure looks like this:

```
<div onmouseleave="func(x)"><div>
```

You can probably just do this:

```
<div onmouseleave="func(x)">
    <div style='padding: 5px'> stuff </div> 
<div>
```

Now anytime you leave the div it should fire the event. Essentially you're creating a padded div, and surrounding it with a wrapper where your actual event lives.

Comment: Not sure how this is any different than padding the original element